# Error during converting string into float phyton

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string value in a float value after convert it in text, the code is:

```
Sell = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, "
                                                                                       "'section-table-body"
                                                                                       "')]//span[text( "
                                                                                       ")='Amazon']//following"
                                                                                       "::div[ "
                                                                                       "2]")))
Sell = Sell.text
Sell = float(Sell)
```

The error I get is this:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '127,36'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the value uses comma `,` to denote the decimal values. Python does not understand `,` as decimal seperator and needs to use dot `.` instead.

Try this :

```
Sell = "127,36"

Sell = ".".join(Sell.split(","))

Sell = float(Sell)

print(Sell)
```

Comment: `".".join(Sell.split(","))` is more simply `Sell.replace(',', '.')`

Comment: Yup. Thank you. This also works. `.join` came first to my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

The comma in the string is not identified as a decimal.
Try this instead

```
Sell = "127,36"
Sell = Sell.replace(',', '.')
Sell = float(Sell)
```